# Regex match bank account numbers, excluding a list of white listed numbers

Tags: regex, exchange-server

I'm creating a custom Exchange DLP template to match account numbers. I've created a Regex which does exactly that, but I now need to exclude company owned bank numbers.

The Regex formula I'm using is the following

(\b\d{2}[\s-]*\d{4}[\s-]*\d{7}[\s-]*\d{2,3}\b)

This will match any of the below

- 01-1234-5678712-02
- 01 1234 5678712 02
- 011234567871202

With As many, or as few spaces or -'s between the groups of numbers as one wants

Now, if I want to exclude

- 01-1234-5678712-01
- 02-4321-7856124-02
- 03-1342-2451653-03

Is there a way to do this, within the same regex, with the knowledge that this list of excluded numbers may grow or shrink throughout the life of the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably better performance-wise to filter out the accounts after capturing using regex. But if you still want to exclude them from the regex you could use negative look-arounds:

```
(?!01-1234-5678712-01|02-4321-7856124-02|03-1342-2451653-03)(\b\d{2}[\s-]*\d{4}[\s-]*\d{7}[\s-]*\d{2,3}\b)
```

(Note: I also added some `*` to your regex in order to fulfill "as many or as few")

Note though that this is slower performance-wise and harder to expand on than simply checking your regex result against a known list of accounts and discarding those that exist.

#### Negative look-ahead

```
(?!{REGEX})
```

Ensures that the REGEX cannot be matched ahead of the current point.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, can't believe it was so simple! I'm aware that squeezing the exclusion list into the same regex isn't ideal, but may be my only option. I plan on looking at alternatives, but wanted this as a backup, so I was 100% Sure this could be done, at all.

Comment: My final expression for this is as follows

(?!01[\s-]*1234[\s-]*5678712[\s-]*01|02-4321-7856124-02|03-1342-2451653-03)(\b\d{2}[\s-]*\d{4}[\s-]*\d{7}[\s-]*\d{2,3}\b)

I have added the [\s-]* 's to the account number exclusions, to ensure all versions (With or without -'s and spaces) are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could use a negative lookahead expression in the beginning:

```
^(?!number1|number2|...)\d\d[\-\s]+\d{4}[\-\s]+\d{7}[\-\s]+\d\d$
```

Make sure you match the beginning/end of the string rather than just boundaries, if needed. (Boundary checks might be fine depending on what you need.)

However, I wouldn't squeeze the exclusion list into that regular expression, because that makes it far harder to maintain. Any chance you could create a second expression for that?

Comment: Thanks, looks like Skogsv gave slightly more detail, so marking his as answer - but thanks again for replying!